# Nginx not serving CSS correctly in simple PHP project

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, static-content

I've seen several examples of this now: `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3001/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"`. But, I've not been able to understand what might be causing it.

The CSS files in my simple PHP project are not being served. The status code is `200`, and the file does load and its contents can be viewed from the developer console. I also checked the `/etc/nginx/mime.types` file and it has an entry for `text/css`. Finally, here's my site config:

```
server {
    listen 3001 default_server;
    listen [::]:3001 default_server;

    server_name _;

    location / { 
        root /media/common/code/projects/newdf;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }   
}
```

Even in the code, the HTML tags specify the type as `text/css`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $server_url; ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $server_url; ?>/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $server_url; ?>/assets/css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $server_url; ?>/assets/css/style.css">
```

I'm at a loss to understand what's going on.

Interestingly, JS files are loaded without error, and if I run the site on the built-in PHP server, there are no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you are serving all content via `php-fpm`, both static content and dynamic content. It is usual to allow `nginx` to serve static content, in which case, `nginx` is responsible for setting the `Content-Type` header based on the file extension.

In your current configuration, everything is passed to `php-fpm` and receives the default `Content-Type` of `text/html`. Presumably you have disabled `security.limit_extensions` to make this work.

You could use two `location` blocks, one for static content and one for dynamic content. The following is based on your question and [this example from the `nginx` wiki](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/):

```
server {
    listen 3001 default_server;
    listen [::]:3001 default_server;

    root /media/common/code/projects/newdf;
    index index.php;

    location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }   
}
```

EDIT: Added the following simplified example for applications that do not require path info:

```
server {
    listen 3001 default_server;
    listen [::]:3001 default_server;

    root /media/common/code/projects/newdf;
    index index.php;

    location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }   
}
```

Comment: So `try_files` is for static content, whereas `fastcgi_split_path_info` is for dynamic? By the way, what does the first line inside the dynamic block do?

Comment: The [`try_files` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) does not serve content - it just tests for the presence of a file within the document root. The [`fastcgi_split_path_info` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_split_path_info) is part of the FastCGI module and breaks down URIs into script name and path info. Your current configuration uses it, so I gave you an example which also uses it. If your application does not use path info, you can simplify the configuration somewhat.

Comment: Oh! Please tell how to simplify it.